# How to determine which angles of a parallelogram with extended side are required for a given point?

Tags: trigonometry, robotics

I am currently trying to determine what servo angles are necessary to align a [robotic arm's](http://www.eezyrobots.it/eba_mk2.html) claw to the given coordinates. Geometrically simplified, the robotic arm is a parallelogram with two servos at one vertex and one side extended further for the claw. Here is a diagram, pardon my drawing skills:

[Simplified Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glIYf.jpg)

The sides marked D are parallel and equivalent, as are the sides marked $C$. $E$ is of fixed length and is attached to $C$ (in reality it is just the extension of the $C$ piece). The servos adjust angles $\angle a$ and $\angle b$ to move sides $D$ and $C$ from the vertical. The claw itself is at the end of $E$, and $x$ refers to the horizontal distance and $y$ the vertical distance from the origin of the two angles $\angle a$ and $\angle b$ (AKA where the servos are placed).

As for what I have tried, I have calculated the claw's coordinates to be $X=D*sin(a)+E*sin(b)$ and $Y=D*cos(a)-E*cos(b)$, but I am unable to solve the system of equations such that I can determine what to set angles $\angle a$ and $\angle b$ to move the claw to a given point. When using substitution, I only end up with an extremely convoluted equation that my calculator cannot parse, leading me to believe I am going down the wrong path. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is the "bottom-most" $C$ segment fixed to the robot? If so, we should name the angle at which that segment is fixed or simplify the problem by having that fixed segment lie on the $x$ axis for instance. Then, one approach might be to try and find the trajectory of the claw (the set of possible coordinates $(X,Y)$ it can pass through) and associated them with a choice of $(a,b)$.

Comment: It also seems to me that if sides marked $C$ and sides marked $D$ are to remain parallel without being compressed or extend (you mention they are equivalent), then you only need one angle to govern the arm's movement and the claw's trajectory is the arc of a circle.

Comment: @orion2112 Unfortunately none of the segments are fixed, as the only fixed point is the axis of the servo motors on angle $DC$. All the lengths remain the same no matter what, but all of the $CD$ or $DC$ vertices can rotate. Servos control the angles $a$ and $b$ separately, fixed to the base of the arm at that bottom vertex.